# Is there a way i could live view my render image?

Tags: 3d-view

I see in tons of tutorials people have tabs like these(see picture) and as they edit there scene the image changes with it. How would I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: You can right click the edges between the different panels in order to create new ones. With this new window you can then change it to be a view of the 3D scene and then go into the camera view there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You open that window to another 3d viewport, then set it to rendered view by pressing z and selecting rendered, then check render region in output properties and continue editing in other windows.